# How to get a DataFrame from the DataFrame with one column as a sum of values of other rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in this way:

```
        shop_id  item_price  item_cnt_day   day   month  year
        59       9.00        1.0            02    01     2013
        59       8.00        2.0            02    01     2013
        25       10.00       4.0            05    02     2013
        25       17.0        1.0            06    01     2013
        25       10.00       1.0            15    01     2013
```

And I try to get the result like following DataFrame:

```
        shop_id  all_revenue  month  year
        59       25.00        01     2013
        25       27.00        01     2013
```

I mean I want to get each shop's revenue in January 2013.

BUT, I don't know how to code in Pandas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html) + [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `sum`

You can assign a series via `eval`, then use `groupby`:

```
res = df.eval('revenue=item_price * item_cnt_day')\
        .groupby(['shop_id', 'month', 'year'], as_index=False)['revenue'].sum()
```

You can, if you wish, [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for January 2013 (before *or* after the above operations):

```
res = res.query('month == 1 & year == 2013')

print(res)

   shop_id  month  year  revenue
0       25      1  2013     27.0
2       59      1  2013     25.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I like filtering the dataframe first, to reduce number of unnecessary calculations:

```
df.query('month == 1 and year == 2013')\
  .assign(all_revenue = df.item_price * df.item_cnt_day)\
  .groupby(['shop_id','month','year'], as_index=False)['all_revenue'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   shop_id  month  year  all_revenue
0       25      1  2013         27.0
1       59      1  2013         25.0
```

***Note:*** Because your column names are "friendly", no spaces nor special characters, you can use `query` method.  If that doesn't work for your column naming then you need to use boolean indexing.

```
df[(df['month'] == 1) & (df['year'] == 2013)]\
  .assign(all_revenue = df.item_price * df.item_cnt_day)\
  .groupby(['shop_id','month','year'], as_index=False)['all_revenue'].sum()
```